# Updating web server from ASP.NET 1.1/2.0 to 3.5

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm still fairly new to ASP.NET development so bear with me.

I'm going to start development on an updated version of an ASP.NET 1.1 website, which I will develop in ASP.NET 3.5. Currently, my development server allows me to run web sites on 1.1 and 2.0. I've had the 3.5 framework installed, but is there any other configuring/issues I should know about? This server will need to keep running the ASP.NET 1.1 web site alongside the 3.5 one I will be developing.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Although I have .NET 3.5 framework installed, when I go into IIS and create a new Virtual Directory, it only gives me the options of 1.1 or 2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToSetAnIISApplicationOrAppPoolToUseASPNET35RatherThan20.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can set each site (indeed, each virtual directory if you want) to use a specific version of the runtime.

You should have no other configuration issues. If the server is set up to run 2.0 sites, you're good to go, since sites written against 3.5 use the 2.0 runtime, plus 3.5 bits if they are available.